# Converting a list of lists to a list of integer

Tags: python-3.x, list

Python newbie question:

I have a list like this:

```
list1 = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

I want to convert to another list like this (an integer that contains the index where 1.0 is located):

```
list2 = [0,2,2,1,2]
```

Tried doing this:

```
d = {[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]:0, 
     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]:1,
     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]:2}

list2 = map(d.get, list1)
```

But no success

Comment: the key of dict should not be mutable.

Comment: What is the conversion from list1 to list2? How is [1.0, 0.0, 0.0] converted to 0? Is it fixed/hardcoded? And why is there suddenly a dictionary `d` when you are asking about list of lists?

Comment: list2 is the index of the '1.0' for each of the lists in the list. The dictionary d is just a method I tried doing.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is at most 1 `1.0` in each list? You can simply loop through the outer list, then for each inner list, find the index of 1.0, and append the index to list2.

Comment: Just `[l.index(1) for l in list1]` if there's a single 1.0 in every list.

Answer (score 0):

Keys of python `dict`s cannot be mutable, the quickest way to modify your existing code would just be to feed `tuple`s in as keys instead:

```
list1 = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
d = {(1.0, 0.0, 0.0):0, 
     (0.0, 1.0, 0.0):1,
     (0.0, 0.0, 1.0):2}
list2 = list(map(lambda x: d.get(tuple(x)), list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
list1 = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]

value_you_want = 1.0

list2 = []
for temp1 in range(len(list1)):
    list2.append(list1[temp1].index(value_you_want))
    
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0] \
     ,[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]

list2=[i.index(1.0) for i in list1 if 1.0 in i]
print(list2)
```